# Numerical fit to a system of linear equations in Python by Least Squares Fit

Tags: python, scipy, linear-regression, data-fitting, lmfit

Suppose that there is a system of equations in the form:
M1 = A1*x + B1*y + C1*z
...
Mn = An*x + Bn*y + Cn*z
where n > 3. M1,...,Mn are experimentally obtained values, thus there is no correct analytical solution to the problem in finding (x,y,z).
A1,...,Cn,M1,...,Mn - all are known.
The problem is to find the (x,y,z) by the least-squares fit method. I could not find the solution for this problem. I've been using lmfit, but I do now know how to make it work if there is no x-axis involved, i.e. I know how to use lmfit only for fitting functions. lmfit, scipy, anything that can make this work? Thanks!

Comment: Well, (M1, ..., Mn) are your observations ("Data") `(x,y,z)` would be your variable parameters, and you have a bunch of other  'A1,B1,...' coefficients.  You should be able to write a residual function for `lmfit.Minimize()` that takes a Parameters instance (with current values for `x`, `y`, and `z`), your `M` data and your coefficients (maybe a dictionary) and computes the residual array (one element data point).   Without actual code, it is hard to be more specific.

Comment: @MNewville Thanks for the reply. Being scientist and not coder, this is still a bit fuzzy to me. The issue is related to: [link](https://groups.google.com/g/lmfit-py/c/7wxHuytfMik?pli=1)
I am still having problems, one of them being that I do not know how to pass the coefficients in the model.

Comment: `from lmfit.printfuncs import report_fit
from lmfit import Parameters, minimize
data = (5,4) #My M1 and M2 values
p_true = Parameters()
p_true.add('x', value = 0)
p_true.add('y', value = 0)
def residual(pars, x, data = None):
    model = 2.1*pars['x'] + 0.9*pars['y'] #2.1 and 0.9 are A1 and B1
    if data is None:
        return model
    return model - data
fit_params = Parameters()
fit_params.add('x',0,0,100)
fit_params.add('y',0,0,100)

out = minimize(residual, fit_params, kws={'data': data})
fit = residual(out.params)
report_fit(out, show_correl=False, modelpars=p_true)`

Comment: Um, you would have to post readable, runnable code.